# Can discord.js-selfbot perform intent based tasks?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
});
```

Can Discord.js-selfbot listen to this event?
Plus can they do
 `message.guild.members.fetch();`?
P.S I know Self-bots are against the TOS. This is for my understanding.

Answers in my previous questions related to this weren't to the point.

Can discord.js-self do the above mentioned?

Comment: **Having in mind how ToS-breaking that is**, I believe everything you can do as bot account, you can do as self-bot. I can tell from experience - as admin of ~10k community, I saw a few self-bots auto-reacting or replying to messages, or new members incoming.

Comment: New members incoming? guildMemberAdd?

Answer (score 1):

User accounts do not receive GUILD_MEMBER_ADD events. What KifoPL might have seen were user accounts handling MESSAGE_CREATE type 7 (https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object-message-types). So, instead of listening to guildMemberAdd, just listen to incoming messages and process the ones that are type 7.